# jQuery Edit Value of Input

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change the value of this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control round-input" id=num_servers">
```

By clicking this

```
 <div class="spinner-buttons input-group-btn"> <button type="button" class="btn spinner-down btn-primary" id="max" name="max"> Click Me </button>
```

With jQuery, any suggestions?

Comment: first give the input text an id

Comment: than refer to it with $("theid").val("in here");

Comment: the imput has a id of num_servers

Comment: It has a typo though, add a " at the beginning of id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
$("#max").click(function(){
    $("#num_servers").val('YOU CLICKED');
})
```

Also, check your `HTML`, you have an error in the input `id`

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/uc0pov2y/

Comment: This worked thanks :) will check mark it when it lets me

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
  $('#max').click(function(){
        $('#num_servers').val("new text");
  })
```

Comment: @DisplayName if you do not want to use the `id` you can use `$('input:text')` to access the textbox

Comment: Why would I use Input or whatever when you select the Input by id

Comment: actually you would not need it in this case, but if you have something to do with all textboxes, for example if you want to change the value of a set of textboxes, then you might prefer `$('input:text')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#max').on('click', function() {
    $('#num_servers').val("the_value_you_want");
});
```